# Motivation for the definition of k-distillability

Tags: entanglement, mathematics, state-distillation

> **Definition of k-distillability**
>
> For a bipartite state $\rho$, $H=H_A\otimes H_B$ and for an integer $k\geq 1$, $\rho$ is $k$-distillable if there exists a (non-normalized) state $|\psi\rangle\in H^{\otimes k}$ of Schimdt-rank at most $2$ such that,
>
> $$\langle \psi|\sigma^{\otimes k}|\psi\rangle < 0, \sigma = \Bbb I\otimes T(\rho).$$
>
> $\rho$ is distillable if it is $k$ for some integer $k\geq 1.$
>
> <sup>[Source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwtGcZsDGRhCTi1VMll0TGVhOTFoWGxHR1FyN2ExSEVEOTd3/view)</sup>

I get the mathematical condition but don't really understand the motivation for $k$-distillability in general, or more specifically the condition $\langle \psi|\sigma^{\otimes k}|\psi\rangle < 0$. Could someone explain where this comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the partial transpose condition is generally good for detecting entanglement, i.e. a bipartite state $\rho$ is certainly entangled if the partial transpose is not non-negative. In other words, if there exists a state $|\psi\rangle$ such that
$$
\langle\psi|I\otimes\text{T}(\rho)|\psi\rangle<0,
$$
then the state is certainly entangled.

If you want to be able to distil some entanglement from $k$ copies then, crudely, you'd like to look at $k$ copies of the partially transposed state, and if that has a negative eigenvalue, you would be able to extract some entanglement.

With that level of explanation, you'd ask why looking at more than one copy is any use -- the eigenvalues of many copies of $\sigma$ are easily related to the eigenvalues of a single copy. However, this is because of the extra condition that $|\psi\rangle$ must be Schmidt rank 1 or less. I presume that this is because you can give an explicit distillation protocol based on the properties of $|\psi\rangle$. Essentially, this is due to the fact that you're trying to project onto a Bell pair which, of course, is Schmidt rank 2.

For a better understanding that the very hand-wavy suggestions I've just given, you'd want to work through page 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9801069

Comment: Isn't the overlap with an entangled two-qubit state an if and only if criterion for distillability?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch What do you mean by that? Even the maximally mixed state has overlap with the maximally entangled state.

Comment: IIRC a state is 1-distillable if (and only if, as I believe -- this was the question) it has a two-qubit subspace which is entangled -- which is what the above criterion says.  I was indeed not very precise in what I wrote, but my point is that AFAIK said criterion is equivalent to distillability.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Sure, but that maybe doesn't really touch the issue of motivation/insight, which I was trying to give.

Comment: I kind of think it does, since it explains why this is *equivalent* to the natural definition of k-distillability?