# Geometric interpretation of 1-distillability

Tags: entanglement, mathematics, state-distillation

<sup>This is a sequel to [Motivation for the definition of k-distillability](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/motivation-for-the-definition-of-k-distillability)</sup>

---

> **Geometrical interpretation from the definition of 1-distillability**
>
> - The eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$ of the partially transposed $1$-distillable states will have Schmidt rank at most 2, i.e.,
>
> $$|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\sum_i\lambda_i^2|ii\rangle\langle ii|, \textit{ where } \sum_i\lambda_i^2=1\tag{17}$$
>
> - The constraint $\sum_i\lambda_i^2=1$ gives rise to a geometric structure in arbitrary $N$ dimensions.
>
> <sup>[Source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwtGcZsDGRhCTi1VMll0TGVhOTFoWGxHR1FyN2ExSEVEOTd3/view)</sup>

**Questions**:

1. In the definition of $k$-distillability (cf. [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/motivation-for-the-definition-of-k-distillability)) we were talking about bipartite density matrices $\rho$ in $H_A\otimes H_B$. In what sense is $|\psi\rangle$ an "eigenstate" of a partially transposed $1$-distillable state? Is for $1$-distillable $\rho$'s the (non-normalized) state $|\psi\rangle \in H$, such that $\langle \psi|\sigma|\psi\rangle < 0$ *necessarily* an eigenstate of $\rho$? Also, can we prove that $\langle \psi|\sigma|\psi\rangle < 0$ for *any* eigenstate of $\rho$?
2. I do not see how the fact that "the eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$ of the partially transposed $1$-distillable states **will have a Schmidt rank at most 2**" is encapsulated within the statement "$|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\sum_i\lambda_i^2|ii\rangle\langle ii|$ where $\sum_i\lambda_i^2=1$".

   As far as I understand, the Schmidt decomposition of a pure state $|\Psi\rangle$ of a composite system AB, considering an orthonormal basis $|i_A\rangle$ for system A and $|i_B\rangle$ for system B, is $$|\Psi\rangle = \sum_i \lambda_i|i_A\rangle|i_B\rangle,$$ where $\lambda_i$ are non-negative real numbers satisfying $\sum_i\lambda_i^2=1$ known as *Schmidt co-efficients*. Now the number of *non-zero* $\lambda_i$'s in the Schmidt decomposition is called Schmidt rank or Schmidt number.  So I don't quite understand the geometric constraint they're talking about; if the Schmidt rank is *at most* 2, then we'd be restricted to only two cases i.e. $\lambda_1^2=1$ and $\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2 = 1$...which aren't so interesting. Am I missing something?

Comment: I agree with your statement in question 2. I don't see it either. (This is often the problem with following slides rather than papers. Is this a typo? Is this an error in a non-refereed document?)

Comment: actually, it doesn't look like a typo because that structure is being used throughout the rest of the slides. It does not look right to me.